# How to retrieve a model field with query parameters in the URL with REST framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a model `Account` with a ForeignKey `user` and a method `total_value()` that returns a `float64`. I would like to GET the float value by entering the account and user primary keys as parameters in the URL.

To do that I catch parameters with `request.query_params` and select the desired `Account` object but the framework throws an error.
How can I do that ?

This is the desired URL fomat and output:

```
https://mysite/api/widget/total/?user=1&account=1
1.22222344
```

Error returned :

```
'Account' object is not iterable
```

**models.py**

```
class Account(TimestampedModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def total_value(self):
        return 1.22222344
```

**serializer.py**

```
class TotalAssetsValueSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ('total_value',)
```

**view.py**

```
class TotalAssetsValueView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = TotalAssetsValueSerializer
    http_method_names = ['get']

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.query_params.get('user')
        account = self.request.query_params.get('account')
        return Account.objects.get(pk=account, user=user)
```

**urls.py**

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register("widget/total", TotalAssetsValueView, basename="account-total")

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

I'm sure there an account with `pk=1` and `user=1`, so maybe my mistake is that I return an object not a queryset. Unfortunnatly when I `filter` instead of `get` it return `[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are returning a single `Account` object, but `get_queryset` method should return `QuerySet` of objects. That's why it throws error that a single object is not iterable.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    user = self.request.query_params.get('user')
    account = self.request.query_params.get('account')
    return Account.objects.get(pk=account, user=user)
```

Depending on what you want to go for, you can change it to single object `QuerySet`:

```
...
return Account.objects.filter(pk=account, user=user)
```

Or completely change whole view approach, but there are many ways to do that.